# Linq divided by zero error?

Tags: asp.net, linq

How can check following code to catch divided by zero error?

```
active = (g.Sum(x => x.Kullanim_Reaktif) / g.Sum(x => x.kullanim_T0)) * 100
```

I want something like this:

```
 if(g.Sum(x => x.kullanim_T0) == 0)
 {
     return 1;
 }
 else
 { 
     return g.Sum(x => x.kullanim_T0);
 }
```

Can I write `if-else` in above linq code line (`g.Sum(x => x.kullanim_T0)`)? And how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
active = (g.Sum(x => x.kullanim_T0) == 0 ? 1 : g.Sum(x => x.Kullanim_Reaktif) / g.Sum(x => x.kullanim_T0)) * 100
```

but more efficient to do:

```
var kSum = g.Sum(x => x.kullanim_T0);
active = (kSum  == 0 ? 1 : g.Sum(x => x.Kullanim_Reaktif) / kSum ) * 100
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I try to write in this line `g.Sum(x => x.Kullanim_Reaktif)` , But this solution is correct solution for me.